# Selecting Multiple %Hash Elements Using @Array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

How does one create a new hash using an array of keys on an existing hash?

```
my %pets_all = ( 

    'rover' => 'dog',
    'fluffy' => 'cat',
    'squeeky' => 'mouse'
);

my @alive = ('rover', 'fluffy');

#this does not work, but hopefully you get the idea.
my %pets_alive = %pets_all{@alive};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a hash *slice*, like this

```
@pets_all{@alive}
```

although that will give you just a list of the corresponding hash values. To create a second hash that has a subset of the elements in the first, write

```
my %pets_alive;
@pets_alive{@alive} = @pets_all{@alive};
```

but if that is your goal then there is probably a better design. Duplicating data structures is rarely necessary or useful

Comment: Thank you!  From your answer, it sounds like there is a way to do this without duplicating data structures?  (a slice of %pets_all based on a list of keys @alive?)

Answer (score 4):

`my %pets_alive = %pets_all{@alive};` is called a [key/value hash slice](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.20.0/pod/perldata.pod#Key/Value_Hash_Slices), and it actually does work since recently-released 5.20.

Before 5.20, you have a couple of alternatives:

- `my %pets_alive; @pets_alive{@alive} = @pets_all{@alive};` (Hash slices)
- `my %pets_alive = map { $_ => $pets_all{$_} } @alive;`

Comment: Thank you.  Is the syntax the same for hash references?

Comment: References always follow the same pattern of replacing `NAME` with `BLOCK`, so if it's `@NAME{EXPR}` and `%NAME{EXPR}` for hashes, it's `@BLOCK{EXPR}` and `%BLOCK{EXPR}` for hash refs. e.g. `@{ $ref }{qw( a b c )}` or `@$ref{qw( a b c )}` (curlies optional around single scalar). See also [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)